# How to set a constant learning rate in HuggingFace Trainer class?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-trainer

How to use the `get_constant_schedule` from transformers to set a constant learning rate in the Trainer class?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the TrainingArguments parameter [lr_scheduler_type](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.lr_scheduler_type) to `constant`

```py
from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="bla", 
    evaluation_strategy="epoch", 
    lr_scheduler_type="constant"
)
```